# for(auto i : c) -- Is there a short way to do it in reverse direction?

Tags: c++

I have a custom container class and defined iterators, so I can do:

```
for (auto i : c)
```

but is there something to iterate in reverse direction?

Something like:

```
for_reverse (auto i : c)
```

Comment: If you want to use boost: `for (auto i : c | reversed)` or `for (auto i : reversed(c))` -- see [boost.adaptors.reversed](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/adaptors/reference/reversed.html)

Comment: @leemes y u no answer.

Comment: @leemes: Wow, Boost's abuse of operator overloads never ceases to amaze me ;)

Comment: @rightfold becoz I unsure

Comment: I suppose boost is a library that provides some extended capabilities.

Comment: @GeorgeKourtis Yeah, boost is in many points a generic extension to the standard library. Some of the new features you see in the standard library came originally from boost, like many C++11 features.

Comment: You could always write a wrapper template to expose `rbegin()` and `rend()` and `begin()` and `end()`.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth s/abuse/use/

Comment: @KonradRudolph: I'll stick with "abuse" - aren't we always taught not to use operator overloads to achieve non-obvious behaviour (i.e. behaviour that doesn't mirror that for primitives)?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth Then you should not use the iostreams from the standard library, to start with ;)

Comment: @leemes: Yes, I know ;)

Comment: I hear you, but there are some cases in which operator overloading with non-mathematical semantics proved successful (and which don't look *that* strange if you're used to it), and among them are definitely stream operators and piping. We could also argue if expression templates with lazy evaluation a la Eigen is operator overloading abuse, although their operators stand for mathematical semantics...

Comment: @OliCharlesworth That’s indeed what we’re taught but I’m starting to feel that this was always a very bad argument invented simply to pacify the Java “operator-overload-is-eeeevil” crowd and it’s simply not true for many libraries. Maybe it’s time to put the “operator overload abuse” myth to rest. I’ve recently started using non-obvious operator overloads pervasively in R and it’s definitely improved my code.

Comment: @KonradRudolph If you do so: always ask yourself if your code is still self-explanatory for readers not knowing your library. I guess then you're definitely on the safe side.

Comment: @leemes That’s a pretty irrelevant criterion. Why would I expect readers who *don’t* know X to understand X? That’s an artificial barrier. I’ve always advocated *not* writing beginner friendly code because that means you have to dumb down the code needlessly.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: Maybe not self-explanatory, but code should at least be *idiomatic*.

Comment: @KonradRudolph I think every library should be written such that client code can be understood without knowing the library (well). I mean, you should understand what's going on *briefly* when looking at code. That means functions / types should have good names, as well as operators should not be abused extremely. However, there are some cases in which this makes only partly sense, or in other words, cases in which you should know the library briefly (but not fully) to derive the unknown from the known parts. E.g. Boost.Spirit: once you know the brief concept, you understand complex expressions

Answer (score 42):

1. You can use boost:

   ```
   #include <boost/range/adaptor/reversed.hpp>

   using namespace boost::adaptors;
   for (auto i : c | reversed)
       ...
   ```

   Or if you don't like operator overloading:

   ```
   #include <boost/range/adaptor/reversed.hpp>

   using namespace boost::adaptors;
   for (auto i : reverse(c))
       ...
   ```
2. You can define a similar helper function using [std::reverse_iterator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/reverse_iterator) so you don't depend on boost:

   ```
   template<typename It>
   class Range
   {
       It b, e;
   public:
       Range(It b, It e) : b(b), e(e) {}
       It begin() const { return b; }
       It end() const { return e; }
   };

   template<typename ORange, typename OIt = decltype(std::begin(std::declval<ORange>())), typename It = std::reverse_iterator<OIt>>
   Range<It> reverse(ORange && originalRange) {
       return Range<It>(It(std::end(originalRange)), It(std::begin(originalRange)));
   }
   ```

   Then you can write:

   ```
   for (auto i : reverse(c))
       ...
   ```

   [**Example**](http://ideone.com/49MORg)

Comment: I really liked the self-implemented solution and I actually learned something about C++11. Thanks!! +1 :)

Comment: Is there a reason to use `std::end` and `std::begin`, rather than `std::rbegin` and `std::rend`? _/ Edit: just saw your comment regarding this on bobah's answer. Not sure I really agree with it, but it is at least the answer to my question. :)_

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Very simple: they are introduced in C++14... Not sure why you should not agree with it ;)

Comment: @leemes: Oh yeah :( I was thinking of `std::vector::rbegin` (and friends) which date back to C++98. You could still make use of them here for those containers which support it, but meh

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit As you see in the history, I first used the member functions. But then I wanted to add support for raw arrays to mirror the compatibility of the "normal" usage of range-based for.

Comment: @leemes: Seems reasonable.

Answer (score 10):

A one-off pain

```
namespace details {
    template <class T> struct _reversed { T& t; _reversed(T& _t): t(_t) {} };
}

template <class T> details::_reversed<T> reversed(T& t) { return details::_reversed<T>(t); }
template <class T> details::_reversed<T const> reversed(T const& t) { return details::_reversed<T const>(t); }

namespace std {
    template <class T> auto begin(details::_reversed<T>& r) -> decltype(r.t.rbegin()) { return r.t.rbegin(); }
    template <class T> auto end(details::_reversed<T>& r) -> decltype(r.t.rend()) { return r.t.rend(); }

    template <class T> auto begin(details::_creversed<T> const& cr) -> decltype(cr.t.rbegin()) { return cr.t.rbegin(); }
    template <class T> auto end(details::_creversed<T> const& cr) -> decltype(cr.t.rend()) { return cr.t.rend(); }
}
```

and then you are able to do the below

```
for (auto x: reversed(c)) ...
```

Comment: As far as I can see, this requires `T` to implement `rbegin()` and `rend()`, which is not the case for simple custom container classes (you probably only want to implement `begin()` and `end()`) as well as for C-arrays. Regarding the latter, you could use `std::rbegin` and `std::rend` since C++14, or `std::reverse_iterator` with `std::begin` and `std::end` since C++11.

Comment: @KonradRudolph - thanks, constancy should be fixed now

Comment: Now your code is running afoul of C++ naming rules which make it illegal to start an identifier with an underscore in the global namespace. I know, no compiler diagnoses this, but it’s invalid nevertheless.

Comment: @KonradRudolph - ok, one more step to ideal... fixed

Comment: You are not allowed to add declarations to the `std` namespace, this code invokes undefined behaviour. Also, even then, in C++14 `std` is not an associated namespace anymore for range-for. Just drop those into the detail namespace. Lastly, you don't need '_creversed'. If `T` is `const`, the normal `_reversed` template works just as well.

Comment: @Xeo - what part of the standard is declaring that and what compiler/version honors it?

Comment: What specifically? The part about adding declarations to `std`, or whether `std` is an associated namespace for range-for?